# Tor keeps shutting down after a few minutes. Help

Tags: windows

So after updating Tor it uses about 50-60% of my cpu and crashes after a few minutes when I have 3 or 4 tabs open. should I just reinstall it or what should I do?

Comment: Can you give more information? Which version of Tor Browser are you using? What version of Windows? Is there an error message? How much memory does your computer have, and how much is Tor Browser using?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reinstalling but second you should look at the specs on your computer. You may also want to check and see if the tabs you are opening are trustworthy because if you have JavaScript enabled on a site which takes advantage of your personal computational power it may start to crash your window.

Please let me know more detail about your hardware if those does not work.